# How to add multiple silent mono audio streams?

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m trying to add silent audio as 8 separate mono streams to a video. I’m able to add one stream but how can I use the same [`anullsrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) input to generate up to 8 streams?

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=48000 -i testfile.mp4 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the audio 8 times.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=48000 -i testfile.mp4 -map 1:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4`